# How do I create a measure to describe the status between two other measures?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two measures [Inv Qty] and [Sold Qty].  Sold is not yet shipped, meaning Inventory isn't reduced yet.  So we want to be able to state whether or not we have enough inventory to meet the demand of what we've sold.  I have this measure, but when I add it to a table visualization, it take several minutes to load and the gives a "not enough memory error".  I expect like the rest of the report that it should take a second or less.  What am I doing wrong ?

```
Status = 
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        [Inv Qty]>=[Sold Qty],"Full",
        [Inv Qty]>0,"Partial",
        "Zero"
    )
```

I've also tried nested IF statements, as follows:

```
Status = IF([Inv Qty]>=[Sold Qty],"Full",IF([Inv Qty]>0,"Partial","Zero"))
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the rest of the report"? Please share  your sample data in text format!

Comment: @Peter The "rest of the report" means the "Table Visualization" to which I'm trying to add this column.  There are 21 columns that show up within half a second when opening the report.  I can't share sample data due to confidentiality.

Comment: Please provide the measure codes [Inv Qty] and [Sold Qty]]

Comment: Both of those are columns in the existing table already.

Comment: @AleisterTanekJavasMraz Thank you for the feedback. Your DAX code consists of simple expression. I can't understand why It gives memory error. It does  not include memory-intensive operations like iterators etc.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: How are inventory and sold tables related?

Comment: @OzanSen They are both columns in the same table.  I wrote them here as two separate tables.

Comment: Inv Qty = SUM(INV[QTY])

Comment: Sold Qty = SUM(INV[QTY SOLD])

Answer (score 0):

I ended up created a new Column instead of a Measure.  This solved the issue.